# Problem with passing evaluated expression to a recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I have encountered this problem many times. The idea of the example recursion is to generate all combination of characters by choosing one character of each element from the input array. Here is working example:

```
def gen_comb(input_arr, result, index, curr_comb):
    if len(curr_comb) == len(input_arr):
        result.append(curr_comb)
        return

    for letter in input_arr[index]:
        gen_comb(input_arr, result, index + 1, curr_comb + letter)

    return result

print(gen_comb(input_arr=['abc', 'def'], result=[], index=0, curr_comb=""))
```

And here is the output: `['ad', 'ae', 'af', 'bd', 'be', 'bf', 'cd', 'ce', 'cf']`. The problem occurs when slightly changing the above code:

```
def gen_comb(input_arr, result, index, curr_comb):
    if len(curr_comb) == len(input_arr):
        result.append(curr_comb)
        return

    for letter in input_arr[index]:
        curr_comb += letter
        gen_comb(input_arr, result, index + 1, curr_comb)

    return result
```

The only difference is adding `curr_comb += letter` outside the method signature. In this case the error is `IndexError: list index out of range` but there is similar examples with wrong result.

The question is:

What is the difference between passing an expression to a recursive function and calculating the expression before to pass to the function?

Comment: `curr_comb + letter` doesn't modify `curr_comb` but `curr_comb += letter` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your function relies on a base case of `len(curr_comb) == len(input_arr)`.  In the function instance where the base case is met, execution stops and the for statement doesn't execute. The way you have designed the function  you expect the base case to be met at *the same time* that you have passed an erroneous index.
- `curr_comb += letter` changes the length of `curr_comb` in the *current* instance of the function. This is *happening* within a for loop. When the *next* function instance returns, **this** for loop continues iteration and the length of `curr_comb` continues to increase.
- Eventually `len(curr_comb) > len(input_arr)` and the base case in the *next* function instance fails, the for statement is evaluated and the code tries to index an item that doesn't exist in `input_arr`.

You can see this by printing or at http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

---

That was just a fancy way of restating @JohnnyMopp 's comment to your question.

---

My answer is specific to your function examples and tries to explain why the second function doesn't work.

> What is the difference between passing an expression to a recursive function and calculating the expression before to pass to the function?

A general answer to this might be:
Both are acceptable: **BUT**

- You have to design the base case to match the rest of the function.
- You have to understand how your function works.
- If you change something in a working recursive function, it is probable that you will have to change something else.

---

However, the more I think about it I'm starting to wonder if it is a bad idea to change the state of something *within* a function instance if it is going to continue executing after the *next* recursive call returns. Seems like you should only alter something for use in the *next* instance. I don't have enough experience but it is starting to smell fishy. Maybe someone will comment. I certainly don't recall reading any prohibitions against it.

Answer (score 1):

```
for letter in input_arr[index]:
        curr_comb += letter
        gen_comb(input_arr, result, index + 1, curr_comb)
```

Above code is doing an aggregration. So if `input_arr[index]` is `'abcd'`, and `curr_comb` is `'h'`, the unrolled loop execution will be as follows:

```
gen_comb(input_arr, result, index+1, 'ha')
gen_comb(input_arr, result, index+1, 'hab')
gen_comb(input_arr, result, index+1, 'habc')
gen_comb(input_arr, result, index+1, 'habcd')
```

But actually it should've been:

```
gen_comb(input_arr, result, index+1, 'ha')
gen_comb(input_arr, result, index+1, 'hb')
gen_comb(input_arr, result, index+1, 'hc')
gen_comb(input_arr, result, index+1, 'hd')
```

Which is the output of the original code:

```
for letter in input_arr[index]:
        gen_comb(input_arr, result, index + 1, curr_comb + letter)
```